# What is the best way to connect lots of wires together?

Tags: power-supply, dc, wiring

I need to power 84 12 VDC devices. Each pulls 0.5 A max. Instead of 84 wall warts, I'd like to create a DC bus with two (redundant) power supplies.  What is the best way to connect together 84 small and 2 large wires?

I expect the connection will be semi-permanent.  The wires will go to plugs that will connect to sockets on the devices, so I can unplug them individually when necessary.  I'll connect in a few extra in case Murphy happens.

Any solution with only one wire per terminal/screw will take up way too much space and be too much work (I'm going to have to do this multiple times).  Some type of IDC connector would be awesome, so I don't even have to strip all those wires.

I'm tempted to use a 10" (25 cm) bolt with 90 washers with wires in between. I may get fancy and crimp ring terminals on the large wires.

Or maybe one of [these](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Terminal-Block-Blue-Terminal-Bus-Bar-10-Positions-Screw-Brass-Terminal-Grounding-Strip-Bus-Bar-Block-Pack-of-5/1764631246) with the large wires each under their own screw and a dozen of the small wires twisted together under each of the others.

I'll probably put whatever I use in a plastic box so it appears neat and workmanlike.  Maybe with the small wires coming out a hole at one end and the large wires the other.  Probably use Anderson connectors for the latter.

Comment: What is the physical arrangement of the devices? Will all the devices draw 0.5A simultaneously at some times? 48A is quite a lot to manage.

Comment: do the individual wires need to be individually removable

Comment: Do you want this to look professional at all?

Comment: How do you replace number 42 if it breaks on your bolt?

Comment: @greybeard How did you come to the 170A?

Comment: With two redundant power supplies, available current may exceed 90 A. I thought automotive fuse blocks might be something to look into (added value: easy to disconnect single outputs (where not using micro3 fuses)), but they seem far between. Delphi/Aptiv seems to have made modular and big blocks, but they may have gone belly up.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a common electrical distributor component called a busbar. This is literally just an insulated bar with several screw terminals mounted to it. All terminals are common to the bar so you do not need to add jumper connections. [Here is an example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075X49RCJ).   For different size wires you would use the appropriate sized crimp terminal. The bars could be mounted into an electrical box to keep everything orderly. Also available in [different colors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075XCLZTF), [higher terminal counts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BD33LJ1K), and [specialized configurations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BYF8FYCG).

[image]
Amazon:
[https://www.amazon.com/Bay-Marine-Supply-Busbar-Distribution/dp/B075X49RCJ?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075X49RCJ)

Comment: A related search term the asker might find useful: Distribution block.

Answer (score 0):

The PSU will be good for almost 50A. If you want to protect the smaller wires from short-circuit damage, you should probably use a fuse block for distribution. Given the voltage range, the are multiple automotive devices that fit the bill.